# How to get the index of a column's occurrence in a query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, row-number

I am trying to get the index / row number of a column's occurrence in a data set to produce result alike the following:

```
| Make        | Model    | Option    | Model Index |
├-------------+----------+-----------+-------------┤
| Lamborghini | Diablo   | SE30 Jota | 1           |
| Lamborghini | Diablo   | SE30      | 1           |
| Lamborghini | Cala     |           | 2           |
| Pontiac     | Trans AM | GTA       | 1           |
| Pontiac     | Trans AM | Firefox   | 1           |
| Pontiac     | GTO      | Judge     | 2           |
| Pontiac     | Fiero    | GT        | 3           |
```

Note that the Model Index should repeat for cars of the same Make and Model with a differing option but should also reset when the make changes. I have managed to find the SQL to get the reset on make changes to happen but as soon as I include the option column, I'll get the wrong results.

```
SELECT
    Makes.Name,
    Models.Name,
    Options.Name,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Makes.Id ORDER BY Models.Name) [Model Index]
FROM 
    Makes
INNER JOIN  
    Models ON Models.MakeId = Makes.Id
INNER JOIN 
    Options ON Options.ModelId = Models.Id
```

Result from this SQL (not desired):

```
| Make        | Model    | Option    | Model Index |
├-------------+----------+-----------+-------------┤
| Lamborghini | Diablo   | SE30 Jota | 1           |
| Lamborghini | Diablo   | SE30      | 2           |
| Lamborghini | Cala     |           | 3           |
| Pontiac     | Trans AM | GTA       | 1           |
| Pontiac     | Trans AM | Firefox   | 2           |
| Pontiac     | GTO      | Judge     | 3           |
| Pontiac     | Fiero    | GT        | 4           |
```

Perhaps what I have wrong here is that I am using `ROW_NUMBER` in my query and I don't think the row number can repeat within a given partition.  I think I need `SomethingElse(PerhapsSomeReferenceToModel) OVER (PARTITION BY Makes.Id ORDER BY Models.Name)` but don't know what the `SomethingElse(PerhapsSomeReferenceToModel)` should actually be!

Comment: Why don't you just hard-code "1" since you know it when you write the rest of the query?

Comment: I think you have current and expected output mixed.

Comment: The desired output was supposed to be an index incrementing for every instance of a given make and model and resetting upon the occurrence of a new Make.  Updated to correct.

Comment: Apologies about the confusion my initial post has created.  I have made a few edits to the data (desired and current) and now confirm they represent the problem I am trying to resolve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me re-phrase your requirement:

- Model index resets when make changes
- Model index repeats for same model

You need `RANK()` instead of `ROW_NUMBER()` or `DENSE_RANK()` if the model index cannot contain gaps:

```
SELECT
    *,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Make ORDER BY Model) AS [Model Index],
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Make ORDER BY Model) AS [Model Index DENSE]
FROM @t
ORDER BY Make, Model
```

[DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5bfbd6da2e02872faf63aa57cf194fe6)

(The above example partition and order by *names*. In practice, you would actually do something like `PARTITION BY MakeID ORDER BY ModelID`).

Comment: So I thought the first option there was the right one but it seems to increment for each Option rather than each Model then reset upon finding a new Make.  Does this sound like what you expected it to do?

Comment: @Matt see revised answer.

Answer (score 0):

For the results with 1-2-1-2-3, your query should be correct. Table aliases also simplify the query:

```
SELECT ma.Name, mo.Name, o.Name,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY mo.MakeId ORDER BY o.Name) as [Model Index]
FROM Makes ma INNER JOIN
     Models mo
     ON mo.MakeId = ma.Id INNER JOIN
     Options o
     ON o.ModelId = mo.Id;
```

I suspect that you want 1-2-1-2-1.  If so, you need to change the `PARTITION BY`:

```
SELECT ma.Name, mo.Name, o.Name,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY mo.MakeId, mo.ModelId ORDER BY o.Name) as [Model Index]
FROM Makes ma INNER JOIN
     Models mo
     ON mo.MakeId = ma.Id INNER JOIN
     Options o
     ON o.ModelId = mo.Id
```